# How to manipulate the Google data studio interface with Google Apps scripts, is there such a possibility?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

It is possible to manipulate this properties of data studio, through Google apps scripts, already searched the documentation available and could not find anything related there?Image with the Elements!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP3DA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate the Data Studio interface using Apps Script.